# How does phylogenetic comparative analysis detect phylogenetic signal in the residuals?

Tags: regression, residuals, phylogeny

A common thing that's stated in the phylogenetic comparative analysis literature is that phylogenetic signal is detected in the residuals of a regression, not in the traits/variables themselves. But how is phylogenetic signal in the residuals detected if it is already controlled for by the method of analysis (e.g. PGLS)?

Comment: The method uses a Maximum Likelihood approach to estimate a phylogenetic signal metric, such as Pagel’s lambda, for the residuals and try to minimise it while also estimating model coefficients. See Revell 2010 for a detailed explanation https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00044.x

Comment: I have read it in full already but still don't understand, hence asking here. I don't understand how it can both be in the residuals and removed from the residuals.